# Dependency for SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, google-play-services, build.gradle

I am trying to implement [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request), but I am unable to find classes like `SmsRetrieverClient`. I'm not able to import them.

Refer to the following sample code:

```
 SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context);
 Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
 task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {});
```

I have added following dependency, after which I am able to refer the classes:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

1. But as this include all service API, I want to know the dependency specific to `SMS Retriever API`

   I have referred to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) doc for all dependency and added following, but it did not work.

   ```
   com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2
   com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.2
   ```
2. Also, is it necessary to have 11.x.x versions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try adding the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:$playServicesVersion"
```

replace `$playServicesVersion` with the play services version you are using.

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.2'
    
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.2'`

Comment: can not this compile statement

Comment: implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.2" worked for me

Comment: Adding implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:12.0.1" resolved my issue

Comment: I made changes as per your suggestion and still getting error, have you found another solution?

Answer (score -2):

Do you have error logs that may show the problem? For the meantime, try the old version first from the [SMS Retriever document](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request):

> The SMS Retriever API is available only on Android devices with Play
>   services **version 10.2** and newer.

Check this one if the old version imports SmsRetrieverClient successfully.

Comment: there is no runtime error. There is compile time error - can not find symbol SmsRetrieverClient - basically it can not import the class.

Comment: That is the version for required apk installed on a device. In you application required gps library version 11+ for using SmsRetriever api.